# PostgreSQL INSERT dynamic value in json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-insert

There are two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id bigserial,
  name varchar(255),
  address varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE user_history (
  id bigserial,
  user_id int8
  user_json json,
  create_date timestamp
)
```

`user.id` is generated by `DEFAULT`.

I want to have a history record for the user being created, but i don't know, how to pass generated `user.id` to json. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_history
VALUES (
  DEFAULT,
  (SELECT id FROM user WHERE name = 'Some name'),
  '{
    "id": GENERATED ID HERE,
    "name": "Some name",
    "address": "Some address"
   }',
  '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
);
```

Postgres 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the top:

```
with c as (SELECT id FROM user WHERE name = 'Some name')
INSERT INTO user_history (user_id,user_json,create_date)
select  id, concat(
  '{
    "id": ',id,',
    "name": "Some name",
    "address": "Some address"
   }')::json,
  '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
from c
;
```

also maybe use `json_build_object` for generating json?..

[here' working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/19a8e/1)

**update**

I did not realyze all keys/values in json come from user table, below is shorter query for it:

```
INSERT INTO user_history (user_id,user_json,create_date)
select  id, json_build_object('id',id,'name',name,'address',address), '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
from "user"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/19a8e/3

Also saving user_json does not make much sence - you can always get it by FK on user_history.user_id

```
t=# select to_json(u) from "user" u;
                  to_json
--------------------------------------------
 {"id":1,"name":"Some name","address":null}
```

Comment: You are missing the `from id`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto yes - thank you. I should have checked my code better

Comment: @VaoTsun i don't quite understand how `json_build_object` works. I would be very glad to pass the whole row from `select`, but i get `ERROR: subquery must return only one column`. Same thing with `row_to_json`. Is there a way to convert whole result to json?

Comment: @gorodkovskaya I added wrking example with your exact schema and my exact statement - can't reproduce errr - rows get inserted.

Comment: @VaoTsun I do `json_build_object((SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'Some name'))`. I guess I use the function wrong

Comment: @gorodkovskaya updated the answer to include `json_build_object`, also I just realyzed almost whole json is fro musers table

Comment: @VaoTsun thank you so much! Getting json directly by FK is a cool feature, but my system requires storing json in table. Thanks anyway, you saved my life =)

Comment: na zdorovje, mojo pochtenie